# jquery.min.js conflicts with jquery-1.4.4

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have both the .js files in single page which carrys out different functions. in jquery.min.js

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $.timeliner({
            startOpen:['#19550828EX', '#19630828EX']
        });
        $.timeliner({
            timelineContainer: '#timelineContainer_2'
        });
        // Colorbox Modal
        $(".CBmodal").colorbox({inline:true, initialWidth:100, maxWidth:682, initialHeight:100, transition:"elastic",speed:750});
    });
```

In jquery-1.4.4 I have a rotating wheel function.

What Should I do , so that both the functions would work in that single page??

Answer (score 1):

if you need to use multiple files on same page.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
<script> $144 = jQuery.noConflict(true);</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
```

Now to access version `1.4.4` you need to use `$144` like

```
$144('.element').val();
```

while `$` for version 1.6.2.

Comment: okay so replace 1.6.2 to with 1.7.1. is this solved ur issue?

Comment: the function which worked with version 1.4.4 is not working with 1.7.1,  i dono why it is not working??

Comment: @Zain because many function get removed when version changed.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery min is a minimized file of jquery (it also has a version). jQuery 1.4.4 is the non-minimized file of jquery version 1.4.4.

You need to ask youself:

1. which jquery version do I need for my application?
2. Do I need the min version or not.

At the end choose one jQuery file and don't add two if it's not something you really need.

Comment: its an old version v 1.7.1

Comment: I guess newer versions have the same functionallity that you need on older versions.

I dont like using two jquery versions in a page if it's not really needed. I think it's a bad practice to do that.

I think you need to investigate why the functionality isn't working with 1.7.1 and does work with 1.4.4.